# Draw trajectory of an object in OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I want to make the codes that draw trajectory as the object's moving when I clicked any position on the screen.

I set the initial center point as a starting point. And I want to set the other point with mouse button clicked (destination point) as variables but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
float v1[3] = { -35.0f,  22.5f, 0.0f };
float v2[3] = { -35.0f, -22.5f, 0.0f };
float v3[3] = { 0.0f,  42.5f, 0.0f };
float v4[3] = { 0.0f, -42.5f, 0.0f };
float v5[3] = { 35.0f,  22.5f, 0.0f };
float v6[3] = { 35.0f, -22.5f, 0.0f };
```

This is the initial position of the object. (6-point star with 2 triangles)

```
float px, py;
float center_s[3] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
float center_d[3] = { px, py, 0.0f };
```

`center_s` is the starting point and `center_d` is the destination point with variable `px`, `py`.

```
void lines(void) {
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glPointSize(5);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3fv(center_s);

    glLineWidth(1);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3fv(center_s);
    glVertex3fv(center_d);
}
```

This function draws trajectory with red lines from `center_s` to `center_d`. Also it draws a center point.

```
case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        x = mx;
        y = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) - my;
        px = x + 35.0;
        py = y + 42.5;
        glutIdleFunc(lines);
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
    break;
```

Here is the problem. When the left mouse button is pressed, the star has to move to the clicked position and calculates the center point of the position and draw the line. But if I run these codes, the movement trajectory is not drawn.

Please let me know what the problem is. Plus, the star must move at a constant speed to the clicked location. (Not teleportation)

Following is the full codes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

float v1[3] = { -35.0f,  22.5f, 0.0f };
float v2[3] = { -35.0f, -22.5f, 0.0f };
float v3[3] = { 0.0f,  42.5f, 0.0f };
float v4[3] = { 0.0f, -42.5f, 0.0f };
float v5[3] = { 35.0f,  22.5f, 0.0f };
float v6[3] = { 35.0f, -22.5f, 0.0f };

float px, py;
float center_s[3] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
float center_d[3] = { px, py, 0.0f };

static GLfloat spin = 0.0;

float x = 400.0f, y = 442.5f;

float color1[3] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
float color2[3] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

int mode = 1;
int rotate = 1;

void init(void);
void triangle_1(void);
void triangle_2(void);
void lines(void);
void display(void);
void spinDisplay_1(void);
void spinDisplay_2(void);
void reshape(int, int);
void changeColor(int);
void mouse(int, int, int, int);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(300, 300);
    glutCreateWindow("6-Point Star");

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void init(void) {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}

void triangle_1(void) {
    glColor3fv(color1);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex3fv(v1);
    glVertex3fv(v4);
    glVertex3fv(v5);

    glEnd();
}

void triangle_2(void) {
    glColor3fv(color2);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex3fv(v2);
    glVertex3fv(v3);
    glVertex3fv(v6);

    glEnd();
}

void lines(void) {
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glPointSize(5);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3fv(center_s);

    glLineWidth(1);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3fv(center_s);
    glVertex3fv(center_d);
}

void display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(spin, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    triangle_1();
    triangle_2();

    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void spinDisplay_1(void) {
    spin = spin + 2.0;

    if (spin > 360.0) {
        spin = spin - 360.0;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void spinDisplay_2(void) {
    spin = spin - 2.0;

    if (spin < 360.0) {
        spin = spin + 360.0;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void reshape(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500.0, 0.0, 500.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void changeColor(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        color1[0] = 0.0f, color1[1] = 0.0f, color1[2] = 1.0f;
        color2[0] = 0.0f, color2[1] = 1.0f, color2[2] = 0.0f;
    }
    else if (n == 2) {
        color1[0] = 1.0f, color1[1] = 1.0f, color1[2] = 1.0f;
        color2[0] = 1.0f, color2[1] = 1.0f, color2[2] = 1.0f;
    }
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int mx, int my) {
    switch (button) {
    case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {
            x = mx;
            y = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) - my;
            px = x + 35.0;
            py = y + 42.5;
            glutIdleFunc(lines);
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {
            if (mode == 1) {
                changeColor(mode);
                mode = 2;
            }
            else if (mode == 2) {
                changeColor(mode);
                mode = 1;
            }
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            if (rotate == 1) {
                glutIdleFunc(spinDisplay_1);
                rotate = 2;
            }
            else if (rotate == 2) {
                glutIdleFunc(spinDisplay_2);
                rotate = 1;
            }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Considering your last three questions, I would recommend you getting a good book about OpenGL programming. You seem to have a problem in every step you add to the program, which means that in the end your whole application is written by some SO-members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a few `glEnd()` and unless you have other plans for `center_s` and `center_d` then you don't need them. As `x` and `y` is `center_s`, while `px` and `py` is `center_d`.

So first of all in `mouse()` just assign the mouse position to `px` and `py` instead of `x` and `y`.

```
case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        px = mx;
        py = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) - my;
    }
```

Now next you need a way to obtain the delta time. Delta time is the time passed since the last frame. *For ease I added the following code to the top of `display()`.*

```
int timeNow = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
float delta = (float)(timeNow - timeLastFrame) / 1000.0f;
timeLastFrame = timeNow;
```

Remember to declare `int timeLastFrame = 0;` among your global variables.

Now (still in `display()`) we can calculate the direction of the travel path. We do this by calculating the difference between the two points. Then calculate the length and normalize the difference.

```
float dx = px - x;
float dy = py - y;

float length = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

dx /= length;
dy /= length;
```

Now you just put it all together.

```
if (length > 1.0f) {
    x += dx * speed * delta;
    y += dy * speed * delta;
}
```

So while `length > 1.0` then we move towards `px` and `py` at the speed of `float speed = 100.0f;` (declare this among your global variables as well).

Just to reemphasize. Yes, do delete `glutIdleFunc(lines)` from `mouse()`. Then we add it in `display()` instead. The full extend of `display()` should look like this now:

```
void display(void) {
    int timeNow = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    float delta = (float)(timeNow - timeLastFrame) / 1000.0f;
    timeLastFrame = timeNow;

    float dx = px - x;
    float dy = py - y;

    float length = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    dx /= length;
    dy /= length;

    if (length > 1.0f) {
        x += dx * speed * delta;
        y += dy * speed * delta;
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(spin, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    triangle_1();
    triangle_2();
    glPopMatrix();

    lines();

    glutSwapBuffers();

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Remember `glutPostRedisplay()`. If not then it won't redraw and thus not animate. Also remember to `#include <math.h>` for `sqrt()`.

Everything before `glClear()` could be moved to your `glutIdleFunc()` callback.

Since there was no need for `center_s` and `center_d` then `lines()` can be boiled down to:

```
void lines(void) {
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glPointSize(5);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2f(px, py);
    glEnd();

    glLineWidth(1);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glVertex2f(px, py);
    glEnd();
}
```

The result should look something like this:

[image]

For future reference. If you don't want to do the linear algebra by hand. Then you can use something like [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you explain more about `dx /= length` and `x += dx * speed * delta`?

Comment: You're welcome! `dx` is the difference between `px` and `x`. So this could be `0` `1000` or anything. We need to normalize that difference so that it's between `-1` and `1`. Basically the direction to the target in the form of a unit/normal vector. This means that we can multiply this vector by `x` and then new position will be exactly `x` away from the position. As so we have our `speed` we multiply it by `delta` (the time since the last frame) so that we know how much to move on frame.

Comment: I think I have to study about linear algebra...And the star should only move when the mouse button is pressed, but currently it moves as soon as I run the program. So I added a global variable `trigger = 0;` and edited the `if` condition `length > 1.0f` to `length > 1.0f && trigger == 1`. Lastly I added `trigger = 1` to `GLUT_DOWN` statement of left button case. But a red line is still drawn from the star to the bottom left corner of the screen. Do I have to change something in `display()` function?

Comment: Yes in `lines()` where the lines are drawn, also add `if (trigger == 1)` so you only draw it while `trigger` is set to `1`.